# Valid Sudoku: How to decrease runtime

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, runtime

Problem is to check whether the given 2D array represents a valid Sudoku or not. Given below are the conditions required

1. Each row must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
2. Each column must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.
3. Each of the 9 3x3 sub-boxes of the grid must contain the digits 1-9 without repetition.

Here is the code I prepared for this, please give me tips on how I can make it faster and reduce runtime and whether by using the dictionary my program is slowing down ?

```
def isValidSudoku(self, boards: List[List[str]]) -> bool:
    r = {}
    a = {}
    for i in range(len(boards)):
        c = {}
        for j in range(len(boards[i])):
            if boards[i][j] != '.':
                x,y = r.get(boards[i][j]+f'{j}',0),c.get(boards[i][j],0)
                u,v = (i+3)//3,(j+3)//3
                z = a.get(boards[i][j]+f'{u}{v}',0)
                if (x==0 and y==0 and z==0):
                    r[boards[i][j]+f'{j}'] = x+1
                    c[boards[i][j]] = y+1
                    a[boards[i][j]+f'{u}{v}'] = z+1
                else:
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat tag information in the question title. The tag system works extremely well here and doesn't need any help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you feel the one-letter variables names clarify what this algorithm is doing, so that it does not even need comments?

Comment: Shouldn't you need to check that the Sudoku can really be solved? It could be that although there are no directly visible inconsistencies, they may still arise as you progress with filling in the missing values...

Answer (score 0):

Simply optimizing assignment without rethinking your algorithm limits your overall efficiency by a lot.  When you make a choice you generally take a long time before discovering a contradiction.

Instead of representing, "Here are the values that I have figured out", try to represent, "Here are the values that I have left to try in each spot."  And now your fundamental operation is, "Eliminate this value from this spot."  (Remember, getting it down to 1 propagates to eliminating the value from all of its peers, potentially recursively.)

Assignment is now "Eliminate all values but this one from this spot."

And now your fundamental search operation is, "Find the square with the least number of remaining possibilities > 1.  Try each possibility in turn."

This may feel heavyweight.  But the immediate propagation of constraints results in very quickly discovering constraints on the rest of the solution, which is far faster than having to do exponential amounts of reasoning before finding the logical contradiction in your partial solution so far.

I recommend doing this yourself.  But https://norvig.com/sudoku.html has full working code that you can look at at need.